# Why is my WD My Passport has a Seagate Device Description?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, external-hard-drive

I bought a brand new WD My Passport 2 TB.

When I'm installing the provided WD Backup Software, it doesn't detect my drive. The setup said "No backup targets found"

[This is the WD Backup Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTWE8.png)

I wanted to see why, so I opened Windows Explorer, then right click on the Drive and choose drive properties. In Hardware Tab, it showed 2 disk drives:

```
ST320LT012-1DG14C
WD My Passport 25E2 USB Device
```

[the properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiGYF.png)

ST320LT012-1DG14C is a Seagate 320GB Hard Disk Number. Why is it here?
Did I bought a fake WD My Passport?

Comment: That properties pages is a **list of all disk drives**. I suspect your PC has a Seagate 320GB disk for the C:?

Comment: Try starting `diskmgmt.msc` (maybe as elevated) and examining the properties of the disk in there -> Details Tab -> Hardware IDs selection

Comment: Is the passport plugged directly into a usb (3?) port with the cable provided?

Comment: Thanks Smock, you're right. It's my laptop's.

Comment: I feel so stupid.

Comment: Although that doesn't really answer the main question why the WD Backup won't see the disk :-/

Comment: Well, yeah. I still have no idea.